# How can I (as a user) check if AP isolation is enabled for a Wi-Fi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, miracast

I suspect AP isolation is enabled on the Wi-Fi network at my workplace as I can't cast my phone screen to another device that supports Miracast.

Casting works just fine on my home network with the same devices connected to my home Wi-Fi.

How can I, as a user with no access to the router configuration know whether or not AP isolation is enabled for any Wi-Fi network? Is it even possible?

Comment: With great difficulty, you could try running network scans or try to ping other IPs within the subnet of your currently connected device, but the whole point of client isolation is to ensure devices can't connect to each other, or, quite often, without even being able to communicate with any wired or other wireless network the router or AP is connected to.

Comment: You tagged with both [chromecast] and [miracast] but those are entirely different... Does Miracast just run over existing networks? I recall it used to create its own mini-AP using Wi-Fi Direct.

Comment: Make sure that at least one device other than yours is connected to your AP. Make some scan of your subnet (ping scan for example), or, if IP of this another device is known, try to access it directly (making sure that the answer for this scan type is not disabled on this another device). If scan fails (except self and default gateway assresses) then your WiFi is in isolated mode. Or this scan type is disabled by AP firewall...

Comment: **PS.** The presence of some another device is obligatory. Single device connected to AP without access to AP settings have no chance to detect if isolated mode enabled or not.

Comment: @grawity I should've just tagged [miracast]. I'll remove [chromecast]. I'm not sure how Miracast works but when connected to the corp wireless, screen mirroring and Miracast didn't work. I used AirScreen on Fire TV to cast my phone's screen to it.

Answer (score 1):

This should be *somewhat* reliable:

1. Find out the phone's IP address. (It is shown deep inside Wi-Fi settings, as well as in some "Wi-Fi analyzer" apps.)
2. From the computer, try to `ping` the phone's address.
3. After a ping (whether it was successful or not), quickly check the computer's ARP cache by running `arp`, `arp -a -n`, `ip neigh`, or such.

   (You can also use tools such as `arping` to do the query directly.)

If ping in step 2 succeds, client isolation is *likely* to be disabled, but that's not yet guaranteed.

If arp in step 3 shows the phone's IP address and its correct MAC address, client isolation is likely disabled. But if doesn't show the phone's IP address at all, or shows it as having no corresponding MAC address, client isolation is probably enabled; and if it shows the wrong MAC address (e.g. identical to the default gateway's MAC) then client isolation is definitely enabled.

Note that there can be more causes to non-working Chromecast:

- The AP might block multicast packets, to prevent misbehaving clients from easily causing battery drain for everyone on the network. They're are also slightly difficult to reliably deliver over Wi-Fi. (Multicast packets are used by clients to discover nearby Chromecast devices.)
- The devices might be on different APs, which are not correctly connected to each other (e.g. it is not uncommon to see a place having two routers with physically separate subnets sharing the same SSID).

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. I followed your instructions and pinged my phone and I was able to do that without issue. I ran `arp -a -n` right after that and I found my phone's IP address and the correct MAC address in there.

Comment: However, when I checked the IP address of the server and the client, they were 192.168.5.138 and 192.168.10.40 respectively. Is that the problem?

Comment: I also changed the phone from DHCP to static mode with the IP set to 192.168.5.179. That didn't help either.

Comment: What netmask do they both show? (It's probably just one very large subnet based on ARP results, though. If it were separate subnets, the ARP entries wouldn't show up at all.) I'm still guessing it has to do with the AP(s) just discarding multicast packets.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. They're both 255.255.240.0